# Jmeter - .jtl is not opening

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

I ran the Non-Gui jmeter script for 3000 users load, so for this 70MB .jtl file was created. Now I tried to open this .jtl in View Result Tree inside jmeter Test Plan, but it doesn't open and throw error saying "Error Loding Result File - See log file".

Can anyone suggest me the solution for this, I want to see response body and exception for failed API's ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you seeing the log file, the file is called [*jmeter.log*](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) and it normally lives under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation or at the place where you launch JMeter from, the reason of failure should be more or less there.

In general if the .jtl file comes from [non-GUI JMeter execution](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) with default [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) there is not much you can get from the View Results Tree listener, you should rather consider [generating HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only) from the .jtl file - it will be way more informative:

```
jmeter -g /path/to/your/file.jtl -o /path/to/dashboard/folder
```